# I get a connection was reset error when uploading large file to the server with ASP.net file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, server

Although I searched from many places, I could not solve this error.It says there is an error related to the web.config file, but **maxRequestLength** and **maxAllowedContentLength** are at the most allowed length.
Web Config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="999999" />
</system.web>

<security>
    <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3294967295" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: How large is the file? How is `maxAllowedContentLength` such a odd number?

Comment: Have you looked at *all* the layers between where your client and server are? Network load balancers, firewalls etc that might have connection limits?

Comment: Connection is reset on files larger than 1 gb.

Comment: I don't have much information about the server and I don't think the error is due to the code.I think server settings should be done.